# libvirt Port Forwarding? (Wiki Guide Non-functional)

Tags: port-forwarding, libvirt

I have setup a hook at `/etc/libvirt/hooks/qemu` with permissions of 755 owned by 0:0 with the following contents:

```sh
#!/bin/bash

if [ "${1}" = "virtualmachine" ]; then
  GUEST_IP=192.168.122.2
  GUEST_PORT=1234
  HOST_PORT=1234

  if [ "${2}" = "stopped" ] || [ "${2}" = "reconnect" ]; then
    /sbin/iptables -D FORWARD -o virbr0 -d  $GUEST_IP -j ACCEPT
    /sbin/iptables -t nat -D PREROUTING -p tcp --dport $HOST_PORT -j DNAT --to $GUEST_IP:$GUEST_PORT
  fi
  if [ "${2}" = "start" ] || [ "${2}" = "reconnect" ]; then
    /sbin/iptables -I FORWARD -o virbr0 -d  $GUEST_IP -j ACCEPT
    /sbin/iptables -t nat -I PREROUTING -p tcp --dport $HOST_PORT -j DNAT --to $GUEST_IP:$GUEST_PORT
  fi
fi
```

However when I start it and attempt to connect via `telnet 192.168.1.1 1234` (I know that is not "correct", just checking the port forward) it fails. The service is running and can be connected to directly via a dedicated port. I can't keep the dedicated port however, as I can't dedicate a physical port for each VM.

The host is running Ubuntu server 19.04 and the guest is running Debian 10.

```
# iptables -L
Chain INPUT (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination         
ACCEPT     udp  --  anywhere             anywhere             udp dpt:domain
ACCEPT     tcp  --  anywhere             anywhere             tcp dpt:domain
ACCEPT     udp  --  anywhere             anywhere             udp dpt:bootps
ACCEPT     tcp  --  anywhere             anywhere             tcp dpt:67

Chain FORWARD (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination         
ACCEPT     all  --  anywhere             192.168.122.2       
ACCEPT     all  --  anywhere             192.168.122.0/24     ctstate RELATED,ESTABLISHED
ACCEPT     all  --  192.168.122.0/24     anywhere            
ACCEPT     all  --  anywhere             anywhere            
REJECT     all  --  anywhere             anywhere             reject-with icmp-port-unreachable
REJECT     all  --  anywhere             anywhere             reject-with icmp-port-unreachable

Chain OUTPUT (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination         
ACCEPT     udp  --  anywhere             anywhere             udp dpt:bootpc
# qemu-system-x86_64 --version
QEMU emulator version 3.1.0 (Debian 1:3.1+dfsg-2ubuntu3.3)
Copyright (c) 2003-2018 Fabrice Bellard and the QEMU Project developers
# libvirtd --version
libvirtd (libvirt) 5.0.0
```

How can I fix the port forwarding issues?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out the issue, turns out I needed to run `iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -j MASQUERADE`.

Now it works!

Comment: You need to add the WAN-facing interface to that rule, otherwise everything will get masqueraded and stuff will subtly break. Of course the default virtual network should already be masquerading, so you probably still have a problem.

Comment: I noticed that the server does not know the IP address of the clients. Which is a bit of an issue. Wonder how I could fix that, and what would the command be to fix the masquerading?

Answer (score 0):

If you run the telnet on the host system, you should extend the rules. To redirect the local-originated packets you should add the DNAT rule into the `nat/OUTPUT` chain. In your case you should add the line under the corresponded condition (start or reconnect):

```
/sbin/iptables -t nat -I OUTPUT -p tcp --dport $HOST_PORT -j DNAT --to $GUEST_IP:$GUEST_PORT
```

Also add the opposite command to remove the rule.

```
/sbin/iptables -t nat -D OUTPUT -p tcp --dport $HOST_PORT -j DNAT --to $GUEST_IP:$GUEST_PORT
```

To list the full rule set with counters better use the `iptables-save -c` command instead the `iptables`, that shows only the filter table by default.

Comment: Unfortunately telnet still can not connect to the guest port, it just sits there doing nothing.

Comment: It does appear as though the rules are being added, as there are mentions of the VM IP and the service port.